# is there a word similar to "guacho" in English?

Tags: word-choice

In spanish the word "guacho" has several meanings. The main ones and I believe somehow related are , breeding of an animal, young animal who lost his mother , kid abandoned by their parents and mean and despicable person. Now all these meanings together doesnt make the word "orphan" to be a good translation at all, in my opinion (I dont think that when someone say orphan also refers to a despicable and mean person. Therefore my question is, is there a word similar to "guacho" in English?

Comment: With the disparate meanings? No.

Comment: Could you add an English sentence or sentences (minus the word you are looking for)? This will fix the context, as it is unlikely one context will follow all definitions. For people, "guacho" seems to describe the person who abandoned someone, while *orphan* describes the abandoned person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spanish, *guacho* takes on different meanings depending on the context. There isn't a similar word in English that will take on all of those meanings depending on context.

In addition to orphan, [another translation](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/guacho) offered is bastard, which captures the bad person definition, as well as carrying some insinuation of unclear parentage. This helps to tie the word into the other meanings of guacho, but again, it is not entirely comparable.

Comment: Yes, bastard sounds like a fair enough translation. Though we also have the word bastardo or bastarda.